# VB Reading data from SQL Server to Array, writing into .CSV

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to read out data from a SQL Server into an array. After that, I'd like to write each line into separate .csv files.

This is my code so far:

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Public SQLcn As New SqlConnection

    Public Function Connect() As Boolean
        SQLcn = New SqlConnection("Server = Server01;Database=PROD;User ID=user; Password = 123")

        Try
            SQLcn.Open()

            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Return False

        End Try
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim SQLQuery As String
        Dim SQLcmd As SqlCommand
        Dim SQLrdr As SqlDataReader
        Dim NAVArray As New ArrayList()
        Call Connect()

        SQLQuery = "SELECT No_ FROM " & "dbo.Database" & " Where No_ LIKE '10007*'"

        SQLcmd = New SqlCommand(SQLQuery, SQLcn)
        SQLrdr = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader()

        While SQLrdr.Read()

            Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
            For count As Integer = 0 To (SQLrdr.FieldCount - 1)
                dict.Add(SQLrdr.GetName(count), SQLrdr(count))
            Next

            NAVArray.Add(dict)

        End While

        ExportCSV(NAVArray, "\\path\path\path")

        SQLcn.Close()

    End Sub

    Function ExportCSV(ByVal Daten As ArrayList, ByVal Pfad As String) As Boolean
        Dim Nummer As Integer

        For Each Nummer In Daten
            Dim csv As IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Pfad & Nummer, False)

            csv.WriteLine("formatcount;formatname;printername;Beschreibung;")
            csv.WriteLine("1;\\path\path\path\Format1.fmt;")
            csv.Close()

        Next

        Return 0
    End Function

End Class
```

The NAVArray does not even get filled with the data.

Additionally, I don't know how to write the data to the `CSV.Writeline`.

EDIT:

The New Code (working so far) looks like this:

```vb
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Public SQLcn As New SqlConnection

    Public Function GetData(databaseColumnNames As String()) As DataTable

        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        Dim csb As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder With {.DataSource = "NAVDB01",
                                                        .InitialCatalog = "NAV110_PROD",
                                                        .UserID = "paz",
                                                        .Password = "****"
                                                        }

        Dim columnNames = " " & String.Join(", ", databaseColumnNames.Select(Function(c) "[" & c & "]")) & " "

        Dim sql = "SELECT " & columnNames & " FROM [dbo.Part1 Part2$Item] WHERE No_ LIKE '10007%'"

        Using conn = New SqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString),
                cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

            Dim DAdap As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            DAdap.Fill(dt)

        End Using

        Return dt


    End Function

    Function CsvLine(a As Object(), separator As Char) As String

        Dim b = a.Select(Function(x) x.ToString()).ToArray()

        For i = 0 To b.Count - 1

            If b(i).IndexOfAny({separator, Chr(42), Chr(10), Chr(13)}) >= 0 Then
                b(i) = b(i).Replace("""", """""")
                b(i) = """" & b(i) & """"
            End If
        Next

        Return String.Join(separator, b)

    End Function

    Sub WriteCsvFiles(destPath As String, headings As String(), dt As DataTable)
        Dim separator As Char = ";"c
        Dim header = String.Join(separator, headings)

        For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows

            Dim destFile = Path.Combine(destPath, r(0).ToString().Trim() & ".csv")

            Using sw As New StreamWriter(destFile)
                sw.WriteLine(header)
                sw.WriteLine(CsvLine(r.ItemArray, separator))
            End Using

        Next

    End Sub
    Private Sub bnDatenVerarbeiten_Click() Handles bnDatenVerarbeiten.Click
        Dim destinationFolder = "\\fileserver02\Folder1"


        Dim columnsToUseSQL = {"Description"}
        Dim columnsToUseCSV = {"formatcount", "formatname", "printername", "Beschreibung"}
        Dim daten = GetData(columnsToUseSQL)


        WriteCsvFiles(destinationFolder, columnsToUseCSV, daten)


    End Sub
End Class
```

About the additional Input.
5 fields will be implemented:
Formatcount As InputBox 
Formatname As Dropdown
printername As Dropown (default value defined by Formatname)
itemnumber As Inputbox (Used as Filter for SQL)
creditor As Inputbox (Used for a second SQL-Statement)

Fields going directly to the csv. :
formatcount
formatname
printername

Fields with the result going to the csv. : 
itemnumber (result e.g. "Description")
creditor (result = "specialcode";"countrycode")

EDIT2:

The current state:

```vb
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Public SQLcn As New SqlConnection

    Public Function GetData(databaseColumnNames As String()) As DataTable

        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        Dim csb As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder With {.DataSource = "Server01",
                                                        .InitialCatalog = "NAV110_PROD",
                                                        .UserID = "paz",
                                                        .Password = "***"
                                                        }

        Dim columnNames = " " & String.Join(", ", databaseColumnNames.Select(Function(c) "[" & c & "]")) & " "

        Dim sql = "SELECT " & columnNames & " FROM [dbo.Part1 Part2$Item] WHERE No_ LIKE '10007%'"

        Using conn = New SqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString),
                cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

            Dim DAdap As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            DAdap.Fill(dt)

        End Using

        Return dt


    End Function

    Function CsvLine(a As Object(), separator As Char) As String

        Dim b = a.Select(Function(x) x.ToString()).ToArray()

        For i = 0 To b.Count - 1

            If b(i).IndexOfAny({separator, Chr(42), Chr(10), Chr(13)}) >= 0 Then
                b(i) = b(i).Replace("""", """""")
                b(i) = """" & b(i) & """"
            End If
        Next

        Return String.Join(separator, b)

    End Function

    Sub WriteCsvFiles(destPath As String, headings As String(), dt As DataTable)
        Dim separator As Char = ";"c
        Dim header = String.Join(separator, headings)

        For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim destFile = Path.Combine(destPath, r(0).ToString().Trim() & ".csv")

            Using sw As New StreamWriter(destFile)
                sw.WriteLine(header)
                sw.WriteLine(CsvLine(r.ItemArray, separator))
            End Using

        Next

    End Sub
    Private Sub bnDatenVerarbeiten_Click() Handles bnDatenVerarbeiten.Click
        Dim destinationFolder = "\\fileserver02\folder"
        Dim Anzahl = 1
        Dim Format = "\\fileserver02\folder2"
        Dim Drucker = "\\PRNSRV\Druckdruck"


        Dim columnsToUseSQL = {"Description", "Description 2"}
        Dim columnsToUseCSV = {"Beschreibung", "Beschreibung 2", "formatcount", "formatname", "printername"}
        Dim daten = GetData(columnsToUseSQL)

        daten.Columns.Add("formatcount", GetType(Integer))
        daten.Columns.Add("formatname", GetType(String))
        daten.Columns.Add("printername", GetType(String))

        daten.Rows.Add(daten.Rows(0).Item("Description"), daten.Rows(0).Item("Description 2"), Anzahl, Format, Drucker)


        WriteCsvFiles(destinationFolder, columnsToUseCSV, daten)


    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Are you sure the query returns anything? Do you really have a table named `Database`? Have you tested the query? Concatenating strings to create a SQL query is a very bad idea, but this time it doesn't do anything, you could have written just `"SELECT No_ FROM dbo.Database Where No_ LIKE '10007*'"`.

Comment: The wildcard character in SQL Server is `%` for multiple characters, or `_` for a single character: [LIKE (Transact-SQL) documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: `For Each Nummer In Daten` How can an ArrayList of Dictionaries have Integers?

Comment: This `GetData()` method will force you to build SQL queries in a way that is crazy-vulnerable to SQL injection issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to select 4 columns from the database, so for the purpose of answering the question I made a table named "Huber" with this data:

```
No_ formatcount formatname  printername Beschreibung
10007       1           Hello   World   Starting "entry".
100071      2           Yellow  Flower  NULL
100072      3           Grey    Rock    Let's have a ; here.
```

You may need some flexibility in which columns to select, so I made the column names an array.

There is a standard for CSV files: [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), so we might as well try to follow that.

It seems to me that in this case it would be simplest to retrieve the data into a DataTable. As each datum will be converted to a String to write to the CSV file, there will be no problem with NULL data from the database this way.

When using a database, it is best to open the connection, do the operation, dispose of the connection. The VB.NET [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) statement takes care of the dispose automatically, even if something goes wrong. The DataAdapter.Fill method does the open and close for you (actually it leaves the connection in the same state as before it was called). Do not use anything like the "Function Connect()" in the question: it will lead to problems.

Given all that, I used this code:

```vb
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Function GetData(databaseColumnNames As String()) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        Dim csb As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder With {.DataSource = "Server01",
                                                        .InitialCatalog = "PROD",
                                                        .UserID = "user",
                                                        .Password = "123"}

        ' Put the column names in square brackets in case a reserved word is used as a column name.
        ' Does not take into account using square brackets in a column name (don't do that).
        Dim columnNames = " " & String.Join(", ", databaseColumnNames.Select(Function(c) "[" & c & "]")) & " "

        Dim sql = "SELECT " & columnNames & " FROM dbo.[Huber] WHERE [No_] LIKE '10007%'"

        Using conn = New SqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString),
                cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)

        End Using

        Return dt

    End Function

    Function CsvLine(a As Object(), separator As Char) As String
        ' Ref: RFC 4180 "Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files"
        ' https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

        Dim b = a.Select(Function(x) x.ToString()).ToArray()

        For i = 0 To b.Count - 1
            ' If the field contains the separator, a double-quote, LF, or CR, then make adjustments:
            If b(i).IndexOfAny({separator, Chr(42), Chr(10), Chr(13)}) >= 0 Then
                b(i) = b(i).Replace("""", """""")
                b(i) = """" & b(i) & """"
            End If
        Next

        Return String.Join(separator, b)

    End Function

    Sub WriteCsvFiles(destPath As String, headings As String(), dt As DataTable)
        Dim separator As Char = ";"c
        Dim header = String.Join(separator, headings)

        For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
            ' Use the first column for the filename:
            Dim destFile = Path.Combine(destPath, r(0).ToString().Trim() & ".csv")

            Using sw As New StreamWriter(destFile)
                sw.WriteLine(header)
                sw.WriteLine(CsvLine(r.ItemArray, separator))
            End Using

        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub bnDatenVerarbeiten_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnDatenVerarbeiten.Click
        Dim destinationFolder = "C:\Temp\Huber"
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationFolder)

        ' The names of the columns in the database...
        Dim columnsToUse = {"formatcount", "formatname", "printername", "Beschreibung"}
        Dim daten = GetData(columnsToUse)

        ' You could use different text for the headers if required.
        WriteCsvFiles(destinationFolder, columnsToUse, daten)

    End Sub

End Class
```

To get 3 files:

**1.csv**

```
formatcount;formatname;printername;Beschreibung
1         ;Hello;World;"Starting ""entry""."
```

**2.csv**

```
formatcount;formatname;printername;Beschreibung
2         ;Yellow;Flower;
```

**3.csv**

```
formatcount;formatname;printername;Beschreibung
3         ;Grey;Rock;"Let's have a ; here."
```

Hopefully I left in enough adjustable parts for you to change it as needed.

**N.B.** If the query is modified to use parameters, e.g. you might want to make the `10007%` into a variable, then you must use SQL parameters to keep it safe from SQL injection.

**Regarding adding columns to the datatable.**

Adding the columns is a good idea, but instead of adding a row with the extra data like this:

<strike>`daten.Rows.Add(daten.Rows(0).Item("Description"), daten.Rows(0).Item("Description 2"), Anzahl, Format, Drucker)`</strike>

You need to add the extra data to each row, like this:

```
For i = 0 To daten.Rows.Count - 1
    daten.Rows(i)("formatcount") = Anzahl
    daten.Rows(i)("formatname") = Format
    daten.Rows(i)("printername") = Drucker
Next
```

Comment: Do i really need the CSVLine Function.
I did an export without it before and it worked fine for me.
What is the benefit ?

Comment: Not all the columns in the csv. are filled from the database.
So i just have to use 2 different "columnsToUse" one for the SQL-Statement and one for the CSV. to write ?

Comment: @JonasHuber It is better to break a program down into smaller parts, so although you could put the code of the CsvLine function inside WriteCsvFiles, it would make it harder to work with if you need to make any changes.

Comment: @JonasHuber Are you saying that you get some data from another source, and that will be added in to the CSV data?

Comment: Okay reasonable.
The next thing is, that there is a space in the name of my database.
dbo.Part1 Part2$Item
What is the syntax to prevent the upcoming error ?
The statement of course just recognizes: "dbo.Part1"

Comment: Yes the additional data will come from inputboxes.

Comment: It is best to avoid spaces in the names of databases and columns, but you can enclose it in square brackets as I showed with `[Huber]`, so it would be `dbo.[dbo.Part1 Part2$Item]`.

Comment: I added the new code to the question.
Just changed some data :)

Comment: @JonasHuber Thanks, but could you explain in the question where the information from the inputboxes should be added? I assume the database column "Description" should be the CSV column "Beschreibung". Are there 3 TextBoxes on the form, which should be used for *all* the CSV files?

Comment: I added some lines.
All the fields will be needed in every .csv

Comment: Okay see you then. The code is working so far and I found kind of a way to add the extra Col. but the data adapter only reads the first line of the result.
I will post the new code as an answer to separate it. Or should I edit the question again ?

Comment: @JonasHuber You should edit the question to add the new information.

Comment: I added the code. Adding the columns like this works fine, but maybe there is a better way. But there are 2 more things:
-get more than one result line
-add a second data tables to the existing one(second SQL result)
Can I just combine 2 data tables somehow ?

Comment: @JonasHuber It looks like the extra data was added as a new row instead of being added to each existing row. I've added a bit at the end of my answer which I think will be the adjustment you need.

Comment: Nice, that worked very well. 
Besides that I get an Error when using [dbo.Part1 Part2$Item] 
Message: Invalid object name dbo.Part1 Part2$Item"."

Comment: @JonasHuber It should be `dbo.[Part1 Part2$Item]`. Notice how the square brackets are for the part, not the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks, the last thing is that I need to edit the name of the file before generating it.

Comment: Yikes! This `GetData()` method promotes some really **BAD** practice, and will force building SQL in a way that's crazy-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn It seemed that it was not originally known which columns were going to be selected, and that they might be changed on a whim. Also, given the new information which appeared afterwards about combining the result with operator-entered data, I would not have used a DataTable.

Comment: The column list isn't the problem. The problem is the OP is likely to take this method and run with it in other places where they also need to do things like substitute a variable for a condition in a where clause. I wouldn't post code like that without adding an optional argument to the method to accept a sequence of SqlParameter objects, as well as the code to use the argument if it has a value, _even if they don't need it for this query_. SQL injection is just too big a concern.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Rather than writing an all-singing all-dancing method to query the database, I added a note about using SQL parameters.

Comment: @AndrewMorton nice work, this answer doesn't deserve to be negative because of fear of SQL injection!

Answer (score 0):

Based in you code, your ExportCSV Function should be like the code below.
You are wrong in parameter treats. Your array list contains Dictionary Types and not Integer Types.
Also if your Array list is empty pay attention on Subs when you retrieve data or query composition etc.
However take a look at this code and try to improve this in your scenario.
I hope it might help you.

```vb
Function ExportCSV(ByVal Daten As ArrayList, ByVal Pfad As String) As Boolean

    Dim CSVseparator As String = "|"
    Dim intProgressive As Integer = 0

    Try

        For Each mDict As Dictionary(Of String, Object) In Daten
            Using sr As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Pfad & "_" & intProgressive)
                Dim row As String = Join(mDict.Values.ToArray, CSVseparator)
                sr.Write(row)
                intProgressive += 1
            End Using
        Next

        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: ArrayList is not recommended for new code. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8#remarks

Comment: As you saw, my explanation starts with “Based in your code…...”, so, your comment is not in the right place under my answer. I think should be better under OP question. And stop follow me.