# Using UTF-8 in VB .net for ä,ö,ü etc

Tags: vb.net

For my current project in need a way to use ä,ö etc. in a datatable that is written to a .csv
It is the same project as in: [VB Reading data from SQL Server to Array, writing into .CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970893/vb-reading-data-from-sql-server-to-array-writing-into-csv)

I know that I need UTF-8 but how do I use it ?

Comment: If you can read the data correctly (the encoding is understood, so the resulting strings represent the original characters correctly), you just need a `StreamWriter` (to write each line to a file), for example. UTF-8 is the default encoding in most IO operations when an Encoding is not specified. If you pre-elaborate all the output, `File.WriteAllLines()` would do the same. If you instead get garbled text when reading from the database, the you need to specify the encoding used when the text was stored. The output method won't change.

Comment: The default is already utf8, so that's probably not what you need.  Most legacy software that reads CSV files assumes Encoding.Default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike VB6/VBScript/VBA, VB.Net strings already use full Unicode internally. You can already put accented characters in your string variables (and string members for other objects), and you don't need to do anything special.

There are three things you do need to watch for, though.

First, you must be sure to use `NVARCHAR` rather than `VARCHAR` for your Sql Server columns, as well as your ADO.Net parameters. You may also need to be careful about what [collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15) you have (but the default is almost certainly fine here).

Second, when you open your StreamWriter, you need to use unicode-capable correct [`Encoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.8). `System.Text.UTF8Encoding` is one option. You could also do `System.Text.UnicodeEncoding` (which is UTF16) or `System.Text.UTF32Encoding` and get accurate output.

Finally, just because you successfully create a unicode CSV file, this does not mean your downstream consumers will handle the file correctly. A lot of text editors and other tools like to assume csv data is ASCII. But that's really outside of your scope. All you can is give them valid data. If they don't process it, that's on them :)

So assuming the database is correct, and based on the other question, you have this code:

```
Sub WriteCsvFiles(destPath As String, headings As String(), dt As DataTable)
    Dim separator As Char = ";"c
    Dim header = String.Join(separator, headings)

    For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim destFile = Path.Combine(destPath, r(0).ToString().Trim() & ".csv")

        Using sw As New StreamWriter(destFile)
            sw.WriteLine(header)
            sw.WriteLine(CsvLine(r.ItemArray, separator))
        End Using

    Next    
End Sub
```

This is close. However, take a look at the remarks in the [documentation for the StreamWriter constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_):

> This constructor creates a StreamWriter with UTF-8 encoding without a Byte-Order Mark (BOM), so its GetPreamble method returns an empty byte array. The default UTF-8 encoding for this constructor throws an exception on invalid bytes. This behavior is different from the behavior provided by the encoding object in the Encoding.UTF8 property.

So we kind of already have UTF-8 data, but to really have a correct UTF-8 file, including correct byte-order handling for certain wide characters, we need to change things just a little bit. Where you have this right now:

```
Using sw As New StreamWriter(destFile)
```

should become:

```
Using sw As New StreamWriter(destFile, False, Encoding.UTF8)
```

It also seems very odd to create a separate file for every row that will all have the same structure. I know it's in your original question, but I'd really push back on that, or find out why, and the maybe re-write the method as so:

```
Sub WriteCsvFile(destFile As String, headings As IEnumerable(Of String), dt As DataTable)
    Dim separator As Char = ";"c
    Dim header As String = String.Join(separator, headings)

    Using sw As New StreamWriter(destFile, False, Encoding.UTF8)
        sw.WriteLine(header)
        For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
            sw.WriteLine(CsvLine(r.ItemArray, separator))
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I could not test it until now.
I'll try it as soon as possible.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I changed the line to:
Using sw As New StreamWriter(destFile, False, Encoding.UTF8)
Error: "Encoding" is not declared.